Prisma P1001 Error: Can't Connect to PostgreSQL in Dockerized Full-Stack Project
I’m currently working on a full-stack e-commerce platform called Rookie Store using Docker for containerization.
I’m facing an issue when trying to build and run the application in Docker containers. Specifically, Prisma fails to connect to the PostgreSQL container during the prisma db push command, throwing the following error:
Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `rookie-store-postgres:5432`
Please make sure your database server is running at `rookie-store-postgres:5432`.

Dockerfile for API (Multi-stage build):
# Stage 1: Build the application
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder
RUN npm install -g pnpm
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY pnpm-lock.yaml ./
COPY pnpm-workspace.yaml ./
COPY package.json ./
COPY apps/api/package*.json apps/api/
COPY packages/*/package*.json packages/
RUN pnpm install --frozen-lockfile
COPY apps/api ./apps/api
COPY packages ./packages
RUN pnpm --filter=api run zenstack generate
RUN pnpm --filter=api run prisma generate
RUN pnpm --filter=api prisma db push
RUN pnpm --filter=api build

# Stage 2: Create the final image
FROM node:18-alpine AS runner
RUN apk add --no-cache netcat-openbsd
RUN npm install -g pnpm
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/package.json ./
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/pnpm-workspace.yaml ./
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/apps/api/package*.json ./apps/api/
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/apps/api/dist ./apps/api/dist
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/apps/api/node_modules ./apps/api/node_modules
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/apps/api/public ./apps/api/public
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/apps/api/views ./apps/api/views
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/apps/api/prisma ./apps/api/prisma
RUN pnpm store prune && rm -rf /root/.cache
CMD ["pnpm", "--filter=api", "start:prod"]



Compose file (multi-stage build, installs dependencies, runs migrations, builds the application):
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: rookie-store-postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "postgres"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 10s
      timeout: 5s
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: apps/api/Dockerfile
    container_name: rookie-store-api
    ports:
      - "7000:7000"
    env_file:
      - apps/api/.env
    networks:
      - rookie-store-network
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy


What I’ve tried:
1 Checked database availability: I used docker exec to confirm that the PostgreSQL container is running and accessible.
2 Verified connection strings: I double-checked the connection strings in the .env file for the API and confirmed that they are correct.
3 Added a health check: I added a health check for the PostgreSQL container to ensure it is fully ready before other services attempt to connect.
4 Tried adjusting the build order: I confirmed that depends_on in docker-compose.yml waits for the PostgreSQL container to be healthy before starting the API container.
What do I need to do in the end?

You can never run migrations or otherwise connect to a database container during an image build.  The linked question has a couple of approaches for Prisma, one using a separate migration container and one using a script that runs at container startup time.
